GPX plotting issues with OpenLayers 7
I have a mapping site that plots points on a UK Ordnance Survey map using Openlayers. This has been running fine for years, running OL 7.5.0. Up to this point everything plotted on the map is a point.
I'm in the process of adding some GPX files to the map and have come across a strange issue where the GPX appears to be placed slightly away from its correct position.
Further investigation shows that if the GPX file contains a Route:
<rtept lat="50.740418303757906" lon="-4.027234660461545">
  <time>2024-08-10T15:32:05Z</time>
  <name>SX 57060 95390</name>
  <sym>Ball Park</sym>
  <extensions>
    <trp:ViaPoint>
      <trp:CalculationMode>Direct</trp:CalculationMode>
    </trp:ViaPoint>
    <gpxx:RoutePointExtension>
      <gpxx:Subclass>000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF</gpxx:Subclass>
    </gpxx:RoutePointExtension>
  </extensions>
</rtept>

then the GPX is plotted in the wrong place - slightly north and west of where it should be. If it contains Tracks with identical lat/long:
<trkpt lat="50.740418303757906" lon="-4.027234660461545">
  <ele>0</ele>
</trkpt>

then it's plotted correctly.
Further investigation shows that this problem disappears with OL6.5.0. I've tried with OL7.0.0 and OL10.0.0 and both of these show the displacement.
I've created two test pages which plot two GPXs with the same route in different formats. The first shows both routes using 7.0.0 - the two GPXs are plotted differently. The second is identical but uses 6.5.0, on this one both routes are plotted in correctly.
Reverting to 6.5.0 is not an option.

You need a later version (>=2.8.0) of proj4, see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/14061

Also it cannot distinguish between elevation (which might affect transforms) and time, which should not.  I have raised a bug report https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/16098

Thanks for the response Mike. I have updated proj4 to 2.12.0 but the issue remains.

It should now work using the OpenLayers dev version script https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@dev/dist/ol.js

Mike, thank you, the two gpxs not display correctly. So are you saying the time was causing the offset?

Elevation affects the transform slightly (about 2 cm per 1000 meter altitude).  In your case the time was being passed as an elevation (somewhere beyond the orbit of the moon) and corrupting the result.
